# cannot find distutils on either conda or pip

Tags: python, conda

It sounds pretty straightforward, but...

I am following a [conda tutorial on packaging](https://conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/source/build-without-recipe.html), which is using `distutils`. I am in a fresh Python3.6 conda environment and I have been trying both `conda install distutils` and `pip install distutils` -- and none of them finds any.

Google did not help.

Comment: Isn't `distutils` part of the standard distribution of python3.6? Are you able to `import distutils`?

Comment: nope that's the problem

Comment: Did you install `conda-build`?